# finding text between specific words in python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract text between specific words in text.
for example:

```
my_list = ['w1 w2 w3 WW w6 w7 w8 WW w9 w10','w1 w2 WW w3 w4 WW w5 w6 w7 WW w8 w9 w10 w11 WW w12 WW w13']
```

So I want to extract words between WW and WW in each sentence. If a sentence has two of WW my code can extract words between them but if a sentence has more than two of WW such as in the second sentence in the above example my code couldn't extract the words between the rest of WW in the sentence. See the code below:

```
word = 'WW'

for sentence in my_list:
   t_b = re.split(word + '|' + word, sentence , re.IGNORECASE)
   word_between = [t_b[1].strip() for t_b[1] in t_b[1].split()]
```

Any suggestions appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: How do you want it to handle more than two instances of 'WW' in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = ['w1 w2 w3 WW w6 w7 w8 WW w9 w10','w1 w2 WW w3 w4 WW w5 w6 w7 WW w8 w9 w10 w11 WW w12 WW w13']
[ j.split() for j in sum( [ i.split(' WW ')[1:-1] for i in my_list ], []) ]
```

Output:

```
[['w6', 'w7', 'w8'],
 ['w3', 'w4'],
 ['w5', 'w6', 'w7'],
 ['w8', 'w9', 'w10', 'w11'],
 ['w12']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how i solved it - without using re, though.

```
my_list = ['w1 w2 w3 WW w6 w7 w8 WW w9 w10','w1 w2 WW w3 w4 WW w5 w6 w7 WW w8 w9 w10 w11 WW w12 WW w13']

for item in my_list:
flag=0
answer=[]
for word in item.split():
    if word=="WW" and flag==0:
        flag=1
    elif word!="WW" and flag==1:
        answer.append(thing)
    elif word=="WW" and flag==1:
        print answer
        answer=[]
```

My output is

```
['w6', 'w7', 'w8']                                                                                                                                                      
['w3', 'w4']                                                                                                                                                            
['w5', 'w6', 'w7']                                                                                                                                                      
['w8', 'w9', 'w10', 'w11']                                                                                                                                              
['w12']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the split builtin function :

```
my_list = ['w1 w2 w3 WW w6 w7 w8 WW w9 w10','w1 w2 WW w3 w4 WW w5 w6 w7 WW w8 w9 w10 w11 WW w12 WW w13']
my_list[1].split('WW')
```

output

```
['w1 w2 ', ' w3 w4 ', ' w5 w6 w7 ', ' w8 w9 w10 w11 ', ' w12 ', ' w13']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the indices and then use list slicing:

```
my_list = ['w1 w2 w3 WW w6 w7 w8 WW w9 w10','w1 w2 WW w3 w4 WW w5 w6 w7 WW w8 w9 w10 w11 WW w12 WW w13']

new_list = [[c for c, d in enumerate(i.split()) if d == "WW"] for i in my_list]

new = [i.split() for i in my_list]

final = [[b[a[i]:a[i+1]][1:] for i in range(len(a)-1)] for a, b in zip(new_list, new)]
```

Output:

```
[[['w6', 'w7', 'w8']], [['w3', 'w4'], ['w5', 'w6', 'w7'], ['w8', 'w9', 'w10', 'w11'], ['w12']]]
```